# Create sort on click functionality

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I need some help in creating a sort on click functionality for table columns. I would like the columns to be sorted when a user clicks the "Full Name" and "Salary" headers. The "Date Joined" column has been sorted. I'm not sure how to sort the other columns. Below are the code of the Employees.js file where the sort functions should be and the App.js file of the column that has been sorted. Here is how it looks in the browser:

[image: link]

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Employees from './components/employees/Employees';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    employees:[]
}
 
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('data.json', {
      headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
     }})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const sortDate = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.dateJoined) - new Date(a.dateJoined))
      this.setState({employees:sortDate})
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar employees={this.state.employees} />
        <Employees employees={this.state.employees} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

Employees.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EmployeeItem from './EmployeeItem';
 
export class Employees extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container' id='table'>
            <div className='row'>
                <table className="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Full Name</th>
                            <th>Date Joined</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {this.props.employees.map(employee => (
                        <EmployeeItem employee={employee} key={employee.id} />
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
 
export default Employees
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the sorting in exactly same way you have done it for `dateJoined` field. Just create a separate function to sort based on the field and pass it as a prop to the `Employees` component.

**Note:** Since your `employees` state variable is managed in App component that's why you should implement the sorting function in App component.

In `App.js`, inside your `App` component, create a function to sort the employee state. The code should look something like:

```js
...
sortEmployees = (field) => {
    let sortedEmployees = [...this.state.employees];
    
    if(field === "fullName") {
        // sorting in reverse order. you can change this based on your preference
        sortedEmployees.sort((a, b) => b.fullName > a.fullName ? 1 : (a.fullName > b.fullName ? -1 : 0));
    } else if(field === "salary") {
        // sorting in reverse order. you can change this based on your preference
        sortedEmployees.sort((a, b) => b.salary - a.salary);
    } else {
        // keeping the default sort to dateJoined. you can modify this according to your business logic
        sortedEmployees.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.dateJoined) - new Date(a.dateJoined));
    }
    
    this.setState({ employees: sortedEmployees });
}
...
```

Add in the `render` part of App component, pass this to the Employees like this:

```
    ...
    <Employees employees={this.state.employees} sortEmployees={this.sortEmployees} />
    ...
```

In the `Employees` component, you need this the sorting on click of the headers. So, add onClick even handler on each of the `<th>` element and call the `sortEmployees` function from there. It should look like:

```js
...
<th onClick={() => this.props.sortEmployees("fullName")}>Full Name</th>
<th onClick={() => this.props.sortEmployees("dateJoined")}>Date Joined</th>
<th onClick={() => this.props.sortEmployees("salary")}>Salary</th>
...
```

*Note: I have skipped the unnecessary details from my solution.*

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubhaw..you're a lifesaver!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please mark it as accepted answer so that it helps others as well :)